# Spark Streaming: Issues when processing time > batch time

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am running a spark streaming (1.6.1) on yarn using DirectAPI to read events from Kafka topic having 50 partitions and writing on HDFS. I have a batch interval of 60 seconds. I was receiving around 500K messages which was getting processed under 60 Sec.

Suddenly spark started receiving 15-20 million messages which took around 5-6 minutes to process with a batch interval of 60 seconds. I have configured `"spark.streaming.concurrentJobs=4"`.

So when batch takes a long time for processing spark initiate concurrent 4 active tasks to handle the backlog batches but still over a period of time batch backlog increases as batch interval is too less for such volume of data.

I have few doubts around this.

1. When I start receiving 15-20 million messages & time to process those messages is around 5-6 minutes with batch interval of 60 Sec. When I check my HDFS directory I see the files created for each 60 Sec with 50 part files, I am little confused here my batch is getting processed in 5-6 minutes, then how it is writing files on HDFS every 1 min & `'saveAsTextFile'` action is called only once per batch. Total records from all the files 50 part files comes around 3.3 million.
2. In order to handle the processing of 15-20 million messages, I configured my batch interval to 8-10 minutes now spark started consuming around 35-40 million messages from Kafka & again its processing time started exceeding batch interval.

I have configured `'spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=50'` & `'spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true'`.

Comment: That rate of 15-20M rec/sec is a momentary peak or constant? If the mean rate increases 40x, I would expect a likewise increase of the cluster infrastructure as well.

Comment: @maasg rate is constant now, My cluster config is 3 node (1 node is shared by kafka and spark client) each with 128 GB ram, 10 cores I tried all possible ways but not able to process this volume of data under 1 min, I need to process this within 1 min batch interval.

Comment: I'd use backpressure to determine the current max throughput and then increase infrastructure accordingly. I think there's no config magic that can give you a 40x capacity increase unless previous resources were heavily over-dimensioned.  From your description, It doesn't seem the case.

Comment: @maasg I have enabled back pressure "spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true" and "spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=50". I did not see back pressure algorithm triggered. I am receiving 550 json messages in one minute batch each json has (24 * 50K) sub json records which I process using gson parser inside mapPartition method. May you please help me with how to determine current max throughput.

Comment: You can do that manually by changing `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` until you find a rate that's sustainable by your system.

Comment: @maasg, so right now I am getting 25 huge json messages /sec , I have already configured max partition as 50? Sustainable means till I face backlog of batches ? How do I calculate throughput and so that I can do calculate h/w sizing. Please help me I want to learn this.

Comment: If your data rate is constantly 15-20M rec/sec, it seems that your resources is not enough. So it is no use to set `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` because the cpus are fully used; And what's more, if the system keep being short for cpu cores, it is also no use to set `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` which would only make the kafka offset lag keep increasing.

Comment: Any resolution .?

Comment: Yes, I tried couple of options like spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=50' & 'spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true and able to achieve some order of success

Answer (score 0):

I think one thing that may have confused you is the relationship between the length of a job, and the frequency.

From what you describe, with the resources available it seems that in the end the job took about 5 minutes to complete. However your batch frequency is 1 minute.

So as a result, every 1 minute you kick off some batch that takes 5 minutes to complete.

As a result, in the end you will expect to see HDFS receive nothing for the first few minutes, and then you keep receiving something every 1 minute (but with a 5 minute 'delay' from when the data went in).